# Making sure windows 7 installs to ssd

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I'm trying to install windows 7. I have an SSD and an HDD. I want to make sure windows installs to the ssd, as opposed to the hdd. How do I do this?

I'm at the screen where you format the drives. I've created new partitions on each, and formatted them both. They both appear as "Primary" partitions.

Should I just leave the hdd unformatted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that screen, you can highlight one of the partitions by clicking on it. When you click "Next" the highlighted partition is where Windows is installed. There is no need to leave one unformatted, though it won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could always unplug the cable to your HDD.

Comment: You could, but it's unnecessary.